# A finiteness question for integrable polynomial distributions on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, foliations

This  question is motivated by the finitness of  limit cycles for polynomial vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Assume that $X,Y$ are two independent polynomial vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that  the distribuation $\{X,Y\}$ is an integrable distribution. So we  have  a foliation.

> Is it true to say that there are only  a  finite number of compact leaves(torus) with nontrivial holonomy?
>
> What is  an example of this situation such that the foliation has at least one compact leaf?